# Java detect double double quotes in String

Tags: java, string, logic

Sample Code

```
public static void main(String args[]){  
String test=null;   
if(some condition)  
   test = "\"abc\"";
else
   test ="def";

// if condition is true , in debug mode when i check the value of test its ""abc"" (double double quote);   
// if condition is false , then value of test is "def" (double quotes only one time);


}
```

Looking for a logic to check whether string has double double quotes . Tried below stuff

```
// test.startsWith("\"\""))  // this didn;t work
```

Comment: `if(test.startsWith("\"\"")){
   System.out.println("has double double qoutes");
  }` works for me

Comment: if (test.charAt(0) == 34 && test.charAt(test.length()-1) == 34) {
      System.out.println("Has double quotes");
   }

34 in ascii table represents doublequote , hence it works fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are checking for 2 `"(double quotes)s` while your string has only one in the beginning. Try below:

```
 test.startsWith("\"");
 test.endsWith("\"");
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks, How to remove these?

Comment: You can use replaceAll method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but make sure "test" is initialized before you perform any operations on it.

You only need to check whether "test" starts with a single double quote, since the first double quote is not part of the content of the string.